# How to save a VisualStyleRenderer to a file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `VisualStyleRenderer` as follows:

```
VisualStyleRenderer renderer = 
    new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Button.PushButton.Hot);
```

How can I save this to an image file (for example, from within the `OnPaint()` function for a form)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't save it to a file, you use it in your paint event:

```
  VisualStyleRenderer renderer = new
         VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Button.PushButton.Hot);
  Rectangle r = new Rectangle(16, 16, 120, 28);
  renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, r);
```

If you are looking to save the result to a file, then create a bitmap and use the `Graphics.FromImage(...)` function to get a graphic to draw on it, then save that image.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(120, 28);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) {
  VisualStyleRenderer renderer = 
    new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Button.PushButton.Hot);
  renderer.DrawBackground(g, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
}
bitmap.Save(@"...\button.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: I know, but I am trying to make a copy of it.

Comment: @Sabuncu Updated post with what I think you are after.

Comment: +1 This works, a huge THANK YOU!  Can you please explain, if you have time, how you arrived at the solution?

Comment: @Sabuncu Not sure what you mean.  I've been programming in WinForms for many years, so I have lots of bumps and bruises from learning how to do things.

Comment: I mean, I had tried using `e.Graphics` instead of creating a new `Graphics` object as you have done.  I don't understand the `Graphics` at all and this is really bugging me to no end.

Comment: @Sabuncu Think of Graphics as the surface you can draw on.  For a form's paint event, the Graphics is the form that you see on the screen.  For an image, the Graphics is the surface of the bitmap.  You need a Graphic object in order to draw something, so I created a bitmap, then created a Graphic object from it using the `Graphics.FromImage()` constructor.  It's the bitmap that has the abilities to save to a file, not the Graphic object.  Don't run this code in a paint event because a paint event runs all the time a refresh happens.

Comment: This problem was really important for me, so I have voted for your other answers to show my appreciation.

Comment: @Sabuncu Appreciate it, but that's called Serial Upvoting, and the StackOverflow engine will delete those upvotes later.

Comment: Hmmm - didn't know about Serial Upvoting.  I tried.  Thanks for explaining the distinction b/w Graphic object and Bitmap, I have a better handle on it now.