# Rounded picturebox with antialias C#

Tags: c#, .net, picturebox, antialiasing

I used an advise from this topic: [Rounded edges in picturebox C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731855/rounded-edges-in-picturebox-c-sharp) to make my picturebox edges rounded. So, I claimed a new control using this code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class OvalPictureBox : PictureBox {
    public OvalPictureBox() {
        this.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
    }
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnResize(e);
        using (var gp = new GraphicsPath()) {
            gp.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width-1, this.Height-1));
            this.Region = new Region(gp);
        }
    }
}
```

But there is my question: how could I add antialias to my control? I read some topics like this: [Possible to have anti-aliasing when drawing a clipped image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053067/possible-to-have-anti-aliasing-when-drawing-a-clipped-image) but there is just drawing functions are used, and I need to implement antialias in my own control, which parent is PictureBox.

I also tried to override OnPaint method to get PaintEventArgs to use the SmoothingMode, but my code sucked and didn`t work properly.
So I deleted it and this is what I have now:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    base.OnPaint(pe);

    using (var gp = new GraphicsPath())
    {
        gp.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1));
        this.Region = new Region(gp);
    }
}
```

What should I add to this method?

Comment: Show us your code that uses `SmoothingMode`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/t052Un0d

Comment: but this code makes my control just white and antialiasing just first instance of this control, others are staying the same (omg)

Comment: oh, i was wrong about other instances: all of them become with antialias BUT just white color

Comment: Antialiasing works by mixing colors. But a pixel either belongs to a Region or it doesn't, so, no, I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Hmm that should work.  What I normally do when testing anti-alias settings, is to draw a big X (I don't mean a _text_ "x") in the space provided and take note of any tell-tale "steps".  Maybe try that first before drawing a filled ellipse as the latter will be hard to tell

Comment: Nope, it works...but randomly, not on all istances

Comment: Micky, to draw the X is not so complicated, but my problem relates to overrided control... and i spectate some strange behavior. For example: at this moment I have 5 such a controls with rounded edges. When I use **SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White)** anti-alias appears only on 2,3 and 5 instances... this is strange, 1 and 4 still rough cutted. And when I use **SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0,0,0,0));** to make the brush transparent - there is no effect at all

Comment: It's unusual that some instances work and some don't.  "Transparency" in WinForms is a bit of an illusion (no pun intended) where one can not even set the background color of a form to `Transparent` compared to WPF where it is done correctly.   Have you thought about doing away with the `PictureBox` and making a `UserControl` considering you are overriding the `OnPaint()` anyway?